# Rotating teardrop shape in SVG around axis point

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to display a bunch of weather stations on a Leaflet map with SVG icons. Right now I'm just trying to get a handle on the drawing part.

The icons are tear shaped and should rotate around the "circle" part of the icon depending on the direction of the wind.

[image: sketch of icons]

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to setup the `transform` and `transform-origin` so that it the icon "stays in place" and rotates around the "circle" in the path.

[image]

In the example below the number should stay in the middle of the circle.

```js
var svg = d3.select('#icon svg');
// this is really done dynamically based on wind direction


var d = 0;
var path = svg.select('path');

// The animated rotation is just to make the example easy to verify.
function rotate(){
  d = (d + 15 < 360) ? d + 15 : 0;
  path.style('transform', 'rotate('+d+'deg)');
  window.setTimeout(rotate, 60);
};

rotate();
```

```css
svg {
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: #ffedfd

}

.station-icon path {
  /** what am I supposed to use here? **/
  transform-origin: center 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="icon" class="leaflet-marker-icon station-icon">
  <svg width="26" height="26">
    <g transform="translate(0,-6)">
      <path class="st0" d="M26,19c0-2.2-0.6-4.4-1.6-6.2C22.2,8.8,13,0,13,0S3.8,8.7,1.6,12.8c-1,1.8-1.6,4-1.6,6.2c0,7.2,5.8,13,13,13
      S26,26.2,26,19z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <text x="13" y="13" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central">6</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative without using `transform-origin` is setting the center of the rotation (here, using magic numbers):

```
path.attr('transform', 'rotate('+d+' 13 19)');
```

```js
var svg = d3.select('#icon svg');
// this is really done dynamically based on wind direction


var d = 0;
var path = svg.select('path');

// The animated rotation is just to make the example easy to verify.
function rotate(){
  d = (d + 15 < 360) ? d + 15 : 0;
  path.attr('transform', 'rotate('+d+' 13 19)');
  window.setTimeout(rotate, 60);
};

rotate();
```

```css
svg {
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: #ffedfd

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="icon" class="leaflet-marker-icon station-icon">
  <svg width="26" height="26">
    <g transform="translate(0,-6)">
      <path class="st0" d="M26,19c0-2.2-0.6-4.4-1.6-6.2C22.2,8.8,13,0,13,0S3.8,8.7,1.6,12.8c-1,1.8-1.6,4-1.6,6.2c0,7.2,5.8,13,13,13
      S26,26.2,26,19z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <text x="13" y="13" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central">6</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Does setting the origin to 60% achieve what you want?

```js
var svg = d3.select('#icon svg');
// this is really done dynamically based on wind direction


var d = 0;
var path = svg.select('path');

function rotate(){
  d = (d + 15 < 360) ? d + 15 : 0;
  path.style('transform', 'rotate('+d+'deg)');
  window.setTimeout(rotate, 60);
};

rotate();
```

```css
svg {
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: #ffedfd

}

.station-icon path {
  /** what am I supposed to use here? **/
  transform-origin: center 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="icon" class="leaflet-marker-icon station-icon">
  <svg width="26" height="26">
    <g transform="translate(0,-6)">
      <path class="st0" d="M26,19c0-2.2-0.6-4.4-1.6-6.2C22.2,8.8,13,0,13,0S3.8,8.7,1.6,12.8c-1,1.8-1.6,4-1.6,6.2c0,7.2,5.8,13,13,13
      S26,26.2,26,19z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <text x="13" y="13" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central">6</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this an answer? Did you even try running the snippet?